# Modifying Web Client Software Factory generation templates to use web application project

Tags: asp.net, wcsf

By default the WCSF uses the web site model but I would like to change it to use the web application model. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304890.aspx

"... Use the templates with the identifier “WAP” in the template name to create Web sites that use the Web Application project model. ..."